# How to spilt pandas series based on a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split the below pandas series and extract the text between the  `/`,`(` and digits.

```
data[source] = 
    AUS / Bundaberg (AUS) 11th Oct
    RPGTV / Doncaster 11th Oct
    AUS / Angle Park (AUS) 11th Oct
    Sky Sports Racing / Nottingham 11th Oct
    AUS / Cannington (AUS) 11th Oct
    NZL / Manawatu (NZL) 11th Oct
    AUS / Albion Park (AUS) 11th Oct
```

I tried using this split function `data[source].str.split('/').str.split('(')` but I also get a `nan` value

my expected output is this.

```
 Bundaberg 
 Doncaster 
Angle Park
 Nottingham
Cannington
Manawatu 
Albion Park
```

Comment: What about `Sky Sports Racing / Nottingham 11th Oct`? This line does not contain `(`. For which line do you get a `nan`?

Comment: @albert I get `nan` on the entire pandas series. the length of the data is longer than what I displayed here, but this subset is a representation of the entire data.

Comment: @albert I was able to extract the text using the below script `data[source].str.split('(\d+)').str[0].str.split('(').str[0].str.split('/').str[1].str.strip()`

Comment: EDIT: You could try `data.source.str.extract(r"/\s+([^(\d)]+)\s+")`.